# Ckan custom organization type

Tags: ckan

I'm looking to create custom organization types in ckan (they need to be organizations because we want to manage permissions with them).

Eg.

- /universities
- /schools
- /tafes

What's the best approach?

I've come up with two possibilities:

---

First:

Use heirarchies, and create parent groups 'universities', 'schools', 'tafes' and add normal organizations with these groups as their parent.

However this requires setting up a lot of custom controllers and actions to get the required url structure, and feels a little hacky.

---

Second

Use IGroupForm with `group_types` set to `['university', 'school', ...]` a custom controller, and defining actions for each - `{'university_list': university_list}`

With the following

```
def university_list(context, data_dict):
    _check_access('organization_list', context, data_dict)
    return _group_or_org_list(context, data_dict, is_org=True)
```

This seems much nicer, however there are three lines inside this function that destroy my hopes and dreams

```
query = query.filter(model.Group.is_organization == is_org)
if not is_org:
    query = query.filter(model.Group.type == group_type)
```

As the universities are orgs, either the filter won't match if I set `is_org` to `False` or because `is_org` is true, it never actually checks the `group_type`

This means I'd have to rewrite the entire `_group_or_org_list` method (to only change those lines!), and suddenly this option seems even more hacky than the first one.

Comment: If it is any help, you could use https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-hierarchyto have an arbitrarily deep tree of organizations so that organizations at the top level 'own' organizations lower down.  This is approach we use on data.gov.uk

Comment: Had come across this, yes - certainly helped with mocking up the initial parts of the first option.
Thanks :)